# How can I find out which systemcall(s) that a POSIX API invoked in Linux?

Tags: linux, system-calls, posix-api

I know that it may invoke one or more systemcalls to implement a POSIX API in Linux, but how to find out which systemcall(s) will been invoked for a specific POSIX API such as `memcpy` or any other POSIX API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strace](https://strace.io/) tool to trace the system calls made by a Linux executable.

You could also inspect the [C library source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git).